# Date filter for facebook conversation/messages using graph API

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook graph API for reading facebook conversation messages using the following url

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/conversation/messages/

like-
t_mid.1466951718460:2af7cf802579518c97/messages
But a conversation may have many messages that are already downloaded. Is there any way to add date filter while reading messages for a conversation? If it is possible, can you please share what should be the querystring for that

Answer (score 0):

**like:**

```
/conversation/messages?since=10 March 2015&until=10 March 2016
```

**summary:**
*since* and *until* must have time format which can converted with *strtotime*()

Comment: This API is not working any more. Tried with chat id with messages with since and until parameter. We are still getting entire result set.